# url not found - Django python

Tags: django-urls

- My urls are automatically translated (Python, from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _)
- The English version is on urls.py then, the translated versions in django.po (one french, one spanish, one dutch)
  Ex in urls.py:

  from django.conf.urls import url
  from django.views.generic import TemplateView
  from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

  from . import views
  from views import ExtraContextTemplateView

  urlpatterns = [
   url(_(r'^contact/$'), views.contact, name='contact'),
  ]

In index.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" 
                      method="post"
                      style="display: none;"
                      id="form-change-lang">{% csrf_token %}
                      <select name="language">
                        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                        {% for language in languages %}
                            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                            </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
                  </form>
```

In setting, common.py I have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

gettext = lambda s: s 
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('nl', _('Dutch')),
]

prefix_default_language = False

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTOSLUG_MODELTRANSLATION_ENABLE = True
```

Basically the problem is that when you are on the website and you click on the flag it translate without any problem, but, if you have a Spanish, French or dutch device it doesn´t find any urls either the English of the other language.